# How to setExtendedAccessToken facebook javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, token, extend

I've been trying to figure out how to extend the access token using the Facebook JavaScript API.

I see a lot of code examples using PHP but JavaScript seems really hard to find.

A PHP SDK method that seems useful is `setExtendedAccessToken()` however this doesn't seem to exist in the JavaScript API or I simply haven't found it yet.

Does anyone have an example of how to use `setExtendedAccessToken()` in the JavaScript SDK or [how to implement this method](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing that client-side.

First of all, if they wanted it to be possible client-side, then they would issue a long-lived token for client-side login from the beginning, don't you think?

And second of all, it requires your app secret, and you don't want to expose that to the client. (So "no way" is not strictly true - but to do it would be really stupid, because of the need for the app secret.)